# Pandast dataframe Table Diff

Tags: python, pandas

I was able to pull the diff between two exactly same dataframes with this logic:

```
targetDF = pd.concat([sourceDataFrame, tardisDataFrame])
targetDF = targetDF.reset_index(drop=True)
columnsGroup = list(targetDF.columns)
targetDF_GroupBy = targetDF.groupby(columnsGroup)
idx = [x[0] for x in targetDF_GroupBy.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
targetDF = targetDF.reindex(idx)
```

I am getting the results as expected.

My problem is, exactly what is different between the two tables. An easy way out is to export it to excel and write a diff macro there.

Is there a better way of doing it within my code?

***Additional Comments:***
My sample diff data could look something like this:

```
Contract  Age  Sex  State  Savings  Checking  Total
A123  23  M  NJ  1000.02  3000.00  4000.02
A123  34  M  NJ  1000.03  3000.00  4000.03
B534  44  F  OH  3000.00  5000.00  8000.00
B534  44  F  OH  3000.00  5000.00  8000.00
C345  33  F  NY  1234.02  5000.00  6234.02
C345 33 F NY 1234.05 5000.00 6234.05
D653 66 M PA 2334.90 4500.06 6834.96
D653 56 M PA 2334.90 4500.07 6834.97
```

OR

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['Contract', 'Age', 'Sex', 'State', 'Savings', 'Checking', 'Total']
data = [['A123', '23', 'M', 'NJ', '1000.02', '3000', '4000.02'],
['A123', '34', 'M', 'NJ', '1000.03', '3000', '4000.03'],
['B534', '44', 'F', 'OH', '3000', '5000', '8000'],
['B534', '44', 'F', 'OH', '3000', '5000', '8000'],
['C345', '33', 'F', 'NY', '1234.02', '5000', '6234.02'],
['C345', '33', 'F', 'NY', '1234.05', '5000', '6234.05'],
['D653', '66', 'M', 'PA', '2334.9', '4500.06', '6834.96'],
['D653', '56', 'M', 'PA', '2334.9', '4500.07', '6834.97'],]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
```

I am not sure of the output to be honest. I could consider a new row under each two rows marked as True or False. Something like this:

```
Contract Age Sex State Savings Checking Total
A123 23 M NJ 1000.02 3000.00 4000.02
A123 34 M NJ 1000.03 3000.00 4000.03
TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
B534 44 F OH 3000.00 5000.00 8000.00
B534 44 F OH 3000.00 5000.00 8000.00
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
C345 33 F NY 1234.02 5000.00 6234.02
C345 33 F NY 1234.05 5000.00 6234.05
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
D653 66 M PA 2334.90 4500.06 6834.96
D653 56 M PA 2334.90 4500.07 6834.97
TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected out put

Comment: The diff between two exactly same dataframes = 0?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @AntonvBR - Yes, look at the sample diff table. It basically is a huge table with two consecutive rows that I need to compare and (sort of) highlight which column is different per Contract (which is the first column)